# Correct way of using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier and custom cells?

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

I am building an iOS app using Rubymotion.
In this app I got a tableview with many rows. Each row got for labels. The main content labels vary in height. Thus the rows are of different height to (by design).

The problem is dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. When I set the same value for all rows I get problems with overlapping rows and duplicates. When I set a unique value for each row it works fine but the scrolling performance is not as good.

What is the correct way of handling custom rows (different heights)?

Thankful for all input!

**UPDATE**

This is my heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath

```
def tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)

    object = @messages.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row)

    labelSize = object.message.sizeWithFont("Arial".uifont(14), constrainedToSize:[250.0, Float::MAX], lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap)

    labelSize.height + 88

  end
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
def tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)

    # Get row data and create row

    data = @messages[indexPath.row]

    # Create the label and add to view

    main_label = UILabel.new
    main_label.frame = [[10, 0],[250, 40]]
    main_label.text = data.sender
    main_label.font = "Arial".uifont(14)
    main_label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor
    main_label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor
    main_label.tag = 1

    # Create the label and add to view

    sub_label = UILabel.new
    sub_label.frame = [[10, 35],[250, 40]]
    sub_label.text = data.message
    sub_label.font = "Arial".uifont(14)
    sub_label.textColor = UIColor.grayColor
    sub_label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor
    sub_label.numberOfLines = 0
    sub_label.sizeToFit
    sub_label.tag = 2

    # Create the label and add to view

    time_label = UILabel.new
    time_label.frame = [[10, 2],[250, 21]]
    time_label.text = data.created_at_human
    time_label.font = "Arial".uifont(13)
    time_label.textColor = BubbleWrap.rgb_color(123, 137, 165)
    time_label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor
    time_label.tag = 3

    # Create the main view

    main_view = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame([[10, 10],[300, sub_label.size.height + 50]])
    main_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor
    main_view.addSubview(main_label)
    main_view.addSubview(sub_label)

    # Create the details view

    details_view = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame([[10, main_view.frame.size.height + 10],[300, 25]])
    details_view.backgroundColor = BubbleWrap.rgb_color(236, 239, 245)
    details_view.addSubview(time_label)                 

    # Create the cell

    cell = UITableViewCell.alloc.initWithStyle(UITableViewCellStyleDefault, reuseIdentifier:nil)
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone

    # Set the data and return cell

    cell.addSubview(main_view)
    cell.addSubview(details_view)

  end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030533/dynamic-uitableview-cell-height/8030716#8030716

Comment: static NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"yourtableViewCell"];
    
    // my custom cell
    yourtableViewCell *cellObj = nil;
        
    cellObj = (yourtableViewCell*) [tableViewObj dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if (cellObj == nil) {
        cellObj = [[[yourtableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

Comment: @RenoJones that's not too relevant as the OP is using RubyMotion

Comment: oh my bad. I apologize.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement

```
- (Float) tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)
```

and return the appropriate height for each cell

```
def tableView tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath
  # calculate the required height
end
```

## Update

Ok so the I see what is going wrong.

For a `UITableViewCell` like this I would probably make a subclass and then just use that. This would look like

```
def tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath)
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier 'MyCell'
    unless cell
      cell = MyCell.alloc.initWithStyle(UITableViewCellStyleDefault, reuseIdentifier: 'MyCell')
    end

    data = @messages[indexPath.row]

    cell.main_label.text = data.sender
    cell.sub_label.text  = data.message
    # ...
end
```

Alternatively if you do not want to subclass then you need to ensure you only add the view's once. You could do this in the `unless` block as this will only be called once for each cell created, but then you need to have some way to find each of the subviews. A common way to find the subviews is using `tag` but this is horrible so I would subclass

Comment: It´s the dequeing/reusing of cells that is messing things up.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Have you set the class that implements this method as the tableView's delegate? `self.tableView.delegate = self`

Comment: Well, the problem is best pratice really. When setting a common identifier I get problems when scrolling (duplicates from reuse). If I set a unique identifier for each row it works but performance is worse.

Comment: Cell reuse is more efficient and in general it just works all you need to keep in mind is that you will be getting back a cell that is already created/configured. In a normal case this is fine as you just set the label and image and everything is fine. If you add views etc then you need to ensure that you only do it once, it will be easier to explain if I can see your implementation

Comment: I have added my cellForRowAtIndexPath. Please see update2. In this code I have removed reusing and it feels fast, but is it ok solution?